# Can't get internet on raspberry "hotspot" when ethernet bridged with my orange pi zero (how to forward wlan0 to eth0?)

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, router, ethernet

**Firstly I want to say I tried "everything" found on the stackexchange websites and forums regarding this issue, nothing solved it, been stuck for 3 days**

For my setup I have a **raspberry pi** that acts as a **hotspot** and a **orange pi zero** that acts as a **router**

> device
>   <=== wifi  ===>
>   raspberry pi 
>   <=== ethernet  ===>
>
> orange pi zero 
>   <=== wifi  ===>
>   Internet

When connecting to my raspberry pi via wifi, **if my raspbery pi is ethernet to my home router**, I have internet in my device. Therefore the problem is not in the hotspot because
I have internet in my device if my hotspot is connected to the router via ethernet. I followed this guide: https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/access-point.md without the bridging

However, when I connect my hotspot to my orange pi zero via ethernet (and the orange pi zero has a valid wifi internet connection, with packets tested) the same system does not work. **I can ssh into my orange pi through my raspberry using their ethernet connection if I am connected to my raspberry pi on wifi** so they are indeed connected. However internet is not being redirected

**Both the raspberry and orange pi zero have ipv4_forward=1.**

The following screenshot is the ifconfig of my **raspberry**:

[image]

My orange pi zero **also has an ethernet address and same submask**. Again, **I can ssh into my orange pi zero through my raspberry pi**.

In the iptables of my orange pi zero I tried several things that I can't recall right now but none of them worked...

Can someone give me a little guidance and / or solution? Been stuck in this for so long

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

First things first: a nice picture can help to explain what you want to do :-)
And then, what OS is running, so advice can be given accordingly. I am usually working this type of stuff on OpenBSD, but here it looks like a unixoide system. 
So you have maybe this config:

```
RASPI                   ODROID                Wifi Router
eth0              int_if     ext_if (wifi)
10.42.0.1  ->  10.42.0.255 - 192.168.0.1  ->  192.168.0.250
```

So: looks like the internal interface on ODROID matches the IP address range, cause you can SSH between both. The external interface on Odroid should not be the same IP address range than you have configured on your RasPi. That will make things easier. Choose a different network, presumably that of your Wifi router, and give the RasPi s.th. else for Wifi (or even better de-activate). Then IP Forwarding / routing, def gateways and firewall comes into play. The RasPi must have default gateway pointing to Odroid. Odroid has def gateway pointing to Wifi router, and port forwarding activated. To start with, I'd de-activate the firewall on Odroid. 
This is as far as I can tell from your setup.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your comment.

I do NOT have access to the router. The router is a public wireless.

Im running *armbian* on orange pi zero. Nothing to do with odroid.

Comment: ahh, oops, OrangePI. Anyhow, the principle remains the same. I am still confused on the setup. You say you have a home router. You connect your OrangePI via eth0 to this home router? In your answer you say, the router is a public wireless... Really a picture with all interfaces would help. Can you ping the external interface of the OrangePi (eth0) from your RasPI? That would assure, routing of packages work. Then if you can ping external interface of OrangePI, try to ping IP address of public WIFI. If not, then default routes are to be verified...